# Sorting file based on "file" output into folders

Tags: files, grep, sort, cygwin

I am having millions of files without extension and I want to sort them into various folders. I am able to identify the files by "file" but then I end with lot of different types which I can process manually.
I would like to use output of "file" to grep i.e. "Word" and then move it into the "office" folder.
I am able to write it for a single filetype, but not for all the filetypes I have. I am missing the conditions if then.
I am using cygwin.
Anyone could help me to give me an idea how to do this?
Thank you!

Petr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `grep`, you could use simple pattern matching in a shell case construct. For example:

```
#!/bin/sh

for f in *; do 

  [ -f "$f" ] || continue

  ftype="$(file -b -- "$f")"

  case $ftype in 
    *"shell script"*)
      echo mv -- "$f" scripts/
      ;;
    *"C source"*|*"C++ source"*) 
      echo mv -- "$f" src/
      ;;

    .
    .
    .

    *) printf '%s: skipping unrecognized type "%s"\n' "$f" "$ftype" >&2
      ;; 
  esac

done
```

The destination directories must exist (although it would be straightforward to conditionally create them, with `mkdir -p`). Remove the `echo`es once you are happy that it is doing the right thing.

Comment: Thank you, this is a nice approach.